# Dependent dropdown boxes not showing values while editing

Tags: html, angularjs

In my application with dependent dropdown boxes not showing values when edited.
When I edit, the first dropdown shows the value but its dependent one doesn't show any values.

I have tried creating a toggle selection function inside the edit function.
But am still facing the same issue.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select id="ddlCategory" ng-model="Data.categoryId" ng-change="ddlCatChange(Data.categoryId)">
            <option ng-value="" disabled selected>Select a Category</option>
            <option ng-selected="Data.categoryId == ca.categoryId" ng-model="Data.categoryId"
                    ng-repeat="ca in CategoryDDL" value="{{ca.categoryId}}">{{ca.categoryname}}
            </option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select ng-model="Data.subcategoryId">
            <option ng-value="" disabled selected>Select a SubCategory</option>
            <option ng-selected="Data.subcategoryId == sca.scbussubcategoryId" ng-model="Data.subcategoryId"
                    ng-repeat="sca in subCatForDDL" value="{{sca.scbussubcategoryId}}">{{sca.subcategoryname}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you put some JSON `Data`. It will help us to replicate and understand the exact issue? Also, you don't need to add `ng-model` directive to `<option>` as you are adding it in `select`.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I solved this issue by calling a timeout function in the js file.